# Why won't MySQL accept this WKT value for a GEOMETRY column?

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I'm trying to convert this simple WKT multipoint value for storage in a GEOMETRY column in my MySQL database

```
select ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT ((-72.92788350000001 41.308274), (-72.996283 41.355198))');
```

It returns null. I can't figure out why - the WKT itself seems to be valid, for example if you view it at https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

So what's the limitation on the MySQL side and how can I get around it? Thanks.

This is on MySQL 5.6 if that matters.

Comment: Thanks. But it fails for me in your link for 5.6.40 as well, returns null.

Comment: i've posted a anwser with a "workaround" for MySQL 5.6 which also works in newer MySQL versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems MySQL version in 5.6 uses a other WKT format.

In MySQL 5.6 you need to use `MULTIPOINT (-72.92788350000001 41.308274, -72.996283 41.355198)` instead off `MULTIPOINT ((-72.92788350000001 41.308274), (-72.996283 41.355198))`

**MySQL version 5.6.40** 
see demo 
 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mddtN7MBTwPmKz1UoDMqVA/8

**MySQL version 8.0.11** 
to verify the result also it is nice the MYSQL 5.6 WKT format also works in newer MySQL versions. 
see demo 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mddtN7MBTwPmKz1UoDMqVA/11

Also `MULTIPOINT (-72.92788350000001 41.308274, -72.996283 41.355198)` and `MULTIPOINT ((-72.92788350000001 41.308274), (-72.996283 41.355198))` both give the same point on https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little new to this, and I'm just passing the WKT written by the Java JTS library, but that gives me somewhere to look.